# VBA Excel cannot edit the text in textbox after cut & pastespecial

Tags: excel, vba

I found a serious problem in my situation. Since I had the textboxes I decided to move them in the different parts of the sheet using cut & pastespecial option.

[image]

Unfortunately I noticed, that my shape is not a textbox anymore. Instead of it it has been turned into the image, where I cannot edit the text inside.

My code looks like this:

```
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextboxLocation1").Cut
 ActiveSheet.Range("AA70").PasteSpecial
 Selection.Name = "TextboxLocation1"

 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Textbox_Location2").Cut
 ActiveSheet.Range("AA71").PasteSpecial
 Selection.Name = "Textbox_Location2"
```

Is it possible to prevent the initial features of my shape before moving (cut & pastespecial) across the sheet?
I guess, that I shall avoid the "Selection" option and use "dim" instead...

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: You could just change the left/top of the shape instead of `Cut`ting and `PasteSpecial`ing.

Comment: I know that, but can I do it according to the cells count?

Comment: What do you mean by cells count?

Comment: Yes. Works on the same principle as `Range`. Get your cell, get it's chords and apply what @BigBen suggested